# BehaviorSubject.next does not update view with async pipe

Tags: angular, ionic2, observable

I try to retrieve Google Places with Google Places Js API and use BehaviorSubject.next to update my Angular view with the async pipe but view is not updating.

Actually sometimes it does after 15 sec. sometimes I have to click somewhere. But what I sure about is that it doesn't update the moment I get results from Google servers... (I console log it).

Here is my search function:

```ts
    import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController, NavParams, ViewController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-new-location-modal',
  templateUrl: 'new-location-modal.html'
})
export class NewLocationModalPage {

  @ViewChild('map') map: ElementRef;

  // ngModel for segment
  googleSearchType: string;

  // Sport retrieved from previous page (newEventForm)
  sport = '';

  // Props used for suggestion func
  mapElem: ElementRef;
  googleService: any;
  places$:BehaviorSubject<any[]>= new BehaviorSubject([]);


  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public viewCtrl: ViewController,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public params: NavParams
  ) {
    console.log('NewLocationModal#constructor');

    // Sport must be retrieved from params
    this.sport = params.get('sport');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // Init Google service
    this.mapElem = this.map.nativeElement;
    this.googleService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.mapElem);

    // Select Suggestion segment
    this.googleSearchType = 'suggestion';
    // Trigger searchSuggestionsForSport()
    this.searchSuggestionsForSport(this.sport);

  }

  onSegmentChange(segment): void {
    console.log('NewLocationModal#onSegmentChange - Selected segment ', segment.value);

    if (segment.value === 'suggestion') {
      this.searchSuggestionsForSport(this.sport);
    }
  }

  searchSuggestionsForSport(sport: string): void {
    console.log('NewLocationModal#searchSuggestionsForSport - Sport ', sport);

    let location = new google.maps.LatLng(48.862725,2.287592000000018);
    let request = {
      location: location,
      keyword: sport,
      rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE
    };

    // Google Places Service


    // NearBy Search
    this.googleService.nearbySearch(request, (places) => {
      // First set of information sent to the async pipe in view
      this.places$.next(places);

      console.log(places);
    });
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
}
```

And view:

```ts
<div *ngFor="let place of places$ | async">
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <ion-card-title>
                {{place.name}} - {{place.rating}}
              </ion-card-title>
              <p>
                {{place.vicinity}}
              </p>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
        </div>
```

Any solution?

Comment: where is the component's class

Comment: I just updated my post with the whole controller code. I initially only put the function to make the post lighter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Maps is known to make code run outside Angulars zone, this "breaks" change detection. Make the code that updates the model run within Angulars zone explicitly:

```ts
 constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public viewCtrl: ViewController,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public params: NavParams,
    private zone:NgZone,
  ) {

...

    // NearBy Search
    this.googleService.nearbySearch(request, (places) => {
      // First set of information sent to the async pipe in view
      this.zone.run(() => this.places$.next(places));
      console.log(places);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Günter, that worked perfectly. So strange though that two Google technologies can't easily work together...

Comment: GoogleMaps is a plain JS library not customized for Angular. The problem is probably caused because the code is initialized outside Angular.

Comment: @Mikias suggestion will work as well. Which one is better mostly depends on what code is executed from the callback invoked outside of Angulars zone. In this case `this.cdr.detectChanges()` would only run change detection on this component and it's children, but theoretically also sibling components could have got a reference to the observable and subscribed, but they still wouldn't run change detection. If you only do `this.foo = this.bar;` in such a callback, then you can be sure no other component will be affected and `detectChanges()` would be fine.

Comment: I have been struggling half a day. Thank you @GünterZöchbauer. Google could write some articles notifying about such behavior.

Comment: @Ricardas are you using https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps I'd assume they cover this issue.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer nop, I was using stock version. But thanks a lot for hint I will use this one instead.

Comment: fantastic! made my day, thank you. so zone.run() is like $scope.$apply(), so to speak. cheers!

Comment: @Nexus not really. Usually you don't need `zone.run()`. It's just for some edge cases that are not covered by Angular automatically. `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` is probably closer to `$scope.$apply()` but you usually only need that when you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` which is encouraged though.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer fabulous. thank you, I'll try the change detection approach too. using zone.run() fixed my issue so we're good to go for now.